# Does TaskStackBuilder addParentStack work in Android 2.3

Tags: android, navigation

I am using the `TaskStackBuilder` and I followed the steps in [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) to open an a `Regular Activity`. I also implemented both `android:parentActivityName` and the `<meta-data android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY..."` in the `Manifest`.

However, when I press back (after opening the Activity) everything works fine in my Galaxy Nexus (4.2) but it doesn't in my HTC Nexus One (2.3.6). The HTC phone closes the `Activity` and goes back to the home screen meanwhile the Galaxy Nexus constructs all the way back to the app main screen.

I can't find a lot of information about this.. is this supported in Android 2.3?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this isn't supported in 2.3. There is a compatibility library that you can use on devices which aren't at API level 16 (JellyBean), but the compatibility library works only on Android 3.0 and up.

See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/TaskStackBuilder.html

Comment: ... now I feel dumb.. I've been looking everywhere and not in the official reference. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

David Wasser's answer is actually incorrect: the support TaskStackBuilder actually works as early as Gingerbread (2.3.7). The documentation only states that the recommended conventions for app navigation using the back key changed in 3.0, not that TaskStackBuilder does not work below 3.0.